# Getting Ignite Client-Server Connection Information

Tags: ignite

In a simple client-server architecture of Apache Ignite, I have 3 Server nodes and 20-30 client node. Ignite Server Cluster has 20 caches and all other clients are accessing those caches.

So the question is When Client connects to Ignite Server Cluster does it connect to every node or one particular node? Also, Can I get to know which server node client is connected to? (Printing server node ID on the client to which it is connected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about Thick Client, it will establish Discovery connection with a single server node but Communication connections to every data node that it needs data from.

Discovery is used only for cluster-wide announcements and is failed over transparently so you should not worry about that one.

Comment: The reason behind question is that Using Kubenetes IPFinder in configurations, in middle of some operations I get IgniteClientDisconnectedException error. I want to check what can be a possible reason. I have written a reconnect logic using futureConnect() But it doesnt work every time.

Comment: Well this is strange, make sure that network connectivity is guaranteed and that nodes use correct IPs.

Comment: I check for same, but no issue found at networking. I tried by load testing it as one possible I found was due to high CPU utilization. But no issue occured. One more observation found that sometimes, while in an idle state too, it throws the same Error.

Comment: Maybe it's due to long GC on nodes. The most often-occurring issue.